# How to Deploy Lambdas from one code base?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

After doing some brief research, I'm receiving conflicting answers regarding best practices for the AWS lambda service. I'm writing a few microservices for my company that will automate the steps for adding clients to our various services: creating api keys, uploading documents to a repo, sending an email, etc.

I have copied and pasted my code for 3 lambdas now (only changing around a few variable values), but, before I start doing this for all of them, I wanted to request if anyone had an easier method. I do know about the ProxyIntegration, where I could use the same lambda for similar requests and differentiate them by their resource paths; however, is there an easier way I could "map" the lambdas to shared code?

I was thinking about using an S3 Object to hold the code, then change the variables by environment variables (which could very well work), but does anyone have any other recommendations or obvious solutions I'm not realizing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very recent feature called [Lambda Layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) that specifically allows you to share code between AWS Lambda functions.

You would build the common code as a library and deploy it as a Layer. Then each individual Lambda function would include that Layer.